# OCR every .png file in a folder

Tags: python, ocr

I want to iterate through every .png file in a folder and print every text contained in the Images. The first iteration works fine but the second gives an Error.

Code:

```
import pytesseract
from PIL import Image
import os

directory = (r'C:\folder...')

for filename in os.listdir(directory):
    if filename.endswith('.png'):
        Image = Image.open(filename)
        im = pytesseract.image_to_string(Image)
        print(im)
```

Output:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Users\Artur\Desktop\Pytesseract_test.py", line 9, in 
>       Image = Image.open(filename) AttributeError: 'PngImageFile' object has no attribute 'open'

What does it mean 'PngImageFile' object has no attribute 'open'? Doesn't `Image = Image.open(filename)` does exactly that?

Thanks in advance

Edit:

The initial PngError is solved but now another Error with PIL library occured:

```
import pytesseract
from PIL import Image
import os

directory = (r'C:\folder...')

for filename in os.listdir(directory):
    if filename.endswith('.png'):
        img = Image.open(filename)
        im = pytesseract.image_to_string(img)
        print(im)
```

Output: (ocr of 'frame_0000.png' is correct and then)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Artur\Desktop\Pytesseract_test.py", line 9, in <module>
    img = Image.open(filename)
  File "C:\Users\Artur\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 2580, in open
    fp = builtins.open(filename, "rb")
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'frame_0001.png'
```

Edit2:

This is very strange. When I do this:

```
for filename in os.listdir(r'folderpath...'):
    print(filename)
```

it works perfectly fine, iterating through every file, printing every filename.

But when I do this:

```
for filename in os.listdir(r'folderpath...'):
    print(filename)
    print(pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open(filename)))
```

an Error is given:

```
Bewegung_UHF_Plots.m
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Artur\Desktop\Pytesseract_test.py", line 19, in <module>
    print(pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open(filename)))
  File "C:\Users\Artur\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 2580, in open
    fp = builtins.open(filename, "rb")
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Bewegung_UHF_Plots.m'
```

Comment: Use double backslash in directory = (r'C:\folder...')

Comment: I got tesseract from snap, better kill that and use the pytesseract one..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change name of variable `Image` to something else like `pic` or `picture`

Comment: Thanks, that helped but another Error occured. Please take a look at the Edit section.

Comment: Are you sure there is a file named frame_0001.png in the current directory

Comment: Yes ofc. I don't tell the programm to read 'frame_0001.png'. It tries to read it by itself. Because it recognizes it but can't read it for whatever reason. However the first iteration works ('frame_0000.png' is read by the program).

Comment: @ArturMüllerRomanov Try this Image.open(open("path/to/file", 'rb'))

Comment: it works to open the file with one or with two "open" functions if you open the file directly by using its filename. But it does not work in the iteration process. Please see Edit2 Section.

Comment: I am opening a new thread and accepting your answer since this is a new problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your first pass creates an object `Image` which is `Image.open(filename)`, or the implementation of the 'open' method from the 'Image' class on a file 'filename'.  This is what you want on every iteration.  Unfortunately, what you've done is boot the 'Image' class out in favor of your new 'Image' object, so that in the second pass the 'Image' in `Image.open(filename)` is not referring to the 'Image' class, as intended, but rather to your 'Image' object.

Solve your problem by changing:

```
Image = Image.open(filename)
im = pytesseract.image_to_string(Image)
```

to:

```
img = Image.open(filename)
im = pytesseract.image_to_string(img)
```